# C++ манипуляции с методами

Tags: c++

В C#:

```
myObj.SomethingHappened += new MyEventHandler(HandleSomethingHappened);

void HandleSomethingHappened(string foo) {
}
```

Как играть в подобном тоне на C++? Как создать некий EventHandler которому можно кормить метод и потом где небудь из него брать собственно етот метод?
Хочу создать клас, обьекту которого можно было бы как-небудь указывать что он будет делать а не с чем он будет что-небудь делать.

Comment: Можно поконкретнее про "любой метод"? Речь про именно функцию-член класса, в противоположность обычной функции?

Comment: Судя по вопросу, вы хотите вызывать свой метод при любом вызове другого? Или каким образом использовать его? Просто хранить адрес метода в объекте и его возвращать? Поставьте вопрос корректно.

Comment: Любой метод, это статические и динамические? С разными аргументами или с одним постоянным списком аргументов? Всё можно сделать, но нужна конкретика.

Comment: Что такое "скормить метод" и "обратно достать метод"?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте класс-оболочку Function для хранения метода, а его экземпляр храните в EventHandler.
По поводу реализации Function: не знаю, как заставить объект вызываться как функцию (наверное, переопределение операторов).
Хранение как поле объекта решает проблему вытаскивания метода куда-то ещё.

Comment: "заставить объект вызываться как функцию" - переопределяется оператор (), такой класс называется функтором. А еще можно использовать лямбда-функцию (которая по сути и является функтором). Правда, ТС настолько мутно изложил свое пожелание, что непонятно что ему нужно вообще.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю вам нужно что-то подобное, в данном примере классу присваевается указатель на лямбду и выполняется действие

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>

class Method 
{
public:
    Method(int (*fptr)(int, int))
    {
        this->bar = fptr;
    }
    void SetFunction(int (*fptr)(int, int))
    {
        this->bar = fptr;
    }
    //В данном случае GetFunction это имя функции
    int (*GetFunction())(int, int)
    {
        return this->bar;
    }
private:
    //Сам наш указатель вообщем то
    int (*bar)(int, int);
};

int main()
{
    //Пример с со сложением
    Method test
    (
        [](int x, int y)
        {
            return x+y;
        }
    );
    std::cout << test.GetFunction()(10,10) << std::endl;

    //Пример с умножением
    test.SetFunction
    (
        [](int x, int y)
        {
            return x*y;
        }
    );
    std::cout << test.GetFunction()(10,10) << std::endl;
}
```